# How to identify intervals for each integer number

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request

I have two lists:

```
lst1 = {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
lst2 = Range[0.1, 10, 0.1];
```

How can find the interval from `lst2` for each integer number in `lst1`?

For example, `lst1` starts with integer `4` corresponding to `0.1` (first element in `lst2`), and it repeats 30 times. Then the 30th element in `lst2` (which is 3) should match with the last `4` in `lst1`. So, the interval of interest for this example is `{4, [0.1, 3]}`, meaning that 4 remains constant in the range [0.1, 3]. I have a very long list about 10000 of monotonically increasing positive numbers in `lst2` and a limited number of integers, positive but not necessarily monotonically increasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Map[{#[[1, 1]], MinMax @ #[[All, 2]]} &] @ 
 SplitBy[Transpose[{##}], First] &[lst1, lst2]
```

> ```
> {{4,{0.1, 3.}}, {5, {3.1, 4.8}}, {4, {4.9, 7.5}}, {3, {7.6, 8.5}},   
>  {2, {8.6, 10.}}}
> ```

Comment: Is there any problem with `Transpose`? I receive an error relating to Transpose.

Comment: can you share the error/warning message?

Comment: `Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {{4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,<<4990>>},{0.0001,0.0002,0.0003,0.0004,0.0005,0.0006,0.0007,0.0008,0.0009,0.001,<<9990>>}} cannot be transposed.` is the error.

Comment: `lst1` and `lst2` should have the same length. If not, you can try `Map[{#[[1, 1]], MinMax @ #[[All, 2]]} &] @  SplitBy[Transpose[{##}], First] &[lst1,Take[ lst2, Length@lst1]`.

Comment: It works now! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

```
Transpose[{First /@ #, MinMax /@ 
  TakeList[lst2, Length /@ #]}] & [Split @ lst1]
```

{{4, {0.1, 3.}}, {5, {3.1, 4.8}}, {4, {4.9, 7.5}}, {3, {7.6,
8.5}}, {2, {8.6, 10.}}}

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

lst1 = {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
   5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
   4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 
   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
lst2 = Range[0.1, 10, 0.1]

(Transpose[{lst1, lst2}] // SplitBy[#, First] & // 
   Map[Through[{First, Last}[#]] &]) /. { {a_, b_}, {c_, 
    d_}} :> {a, {b, d}}
```

---

I wouldn't run it on a very long list, but for variety:

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
SequenceReplace[Transpose[{lst1, lst2}],
 k : {{a_, b_}, Shortest[{a_, _} ..], {a_, d_}} :> {a, {Last@First@k, 
    Last@Last@k}}]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{4, {0.1, 3.}}, {5, {3.1, 4.8}}, {4, {4.9, 7.5}}, {3, {7.6,
> 8.5}}, {2, {8.6, 10.}}}

Answer (score 4):

```
lst1 = {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
        4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
        5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
        4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
        3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};

lst2 = Range[0.1, 10, 0.1];
```

---

A variant of @kglr's answer:

```
{#1[[1]], #2[[{1, -1}]]} & @@@ Map[Thread]@SplitBy[Thread[{lst1, lst2}], First]
```

*Result:*

> {{4, {0.1, 3.}}, {5, {3.1, 4.8}}, {4, {4.9, 7.5}}, {3, {7.6, 8.5}}, {2, {8.6, 10.}}}

Or using `SequenceCases`:

```
patt = k : {Shortest[{a_, _} ..]} :> {a, {k[[1, -1]], k[[-1, 2]]}};

SequenceCases[Thread[{lst1, lst2}], patt]
```

*Result:*

> {{4, {0.1, 3.}}, {5, {3.1, 4.8}}, {4, {4.9, 7.5}}, {3, {7.6, 8.5}}, {2, {8.6, 10.}}}

Answer (score 2):

```
FoldPairList[
  TakeDrop, 
  lst2, 
  Map[Length] @ Split[lst1], 
  {lst1[[-1 - Length @ Last @ #]], #[[1, {1, -1}]]} &]
```

> ```
> {{4, {0.1, 3.}}, {5, {3.1, 4.8}}, {4, {4.9, 7.5}},   
>  {3, {7.6, 8.5}}, {2, {8.6, 10.}}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
MapThread[
   {First @ #1, MinMax @ #2} &,
   {#, Internal`CopyListStructure[#, lst2]}] & [Split @ lst1]
```

{{4, {0.1, 3.}}, {5, {3.1, 4.8}}, {4, {4.9, 7.5}}, {3, {7.6,
8.5}}, {2, {8.6, 10.}}}